# Binary addition using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

How do I transform below JSON using JOLT

1. Input will be array of strings
2. This string will be binary number , 0 or 1.

I want to perform binary addition and then split resultant array as split and every element should be a seperate property

```json
{
  "binaryarray": [
    "0100",
    "0010"
  ]
}
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "field1" : 0,
  "field2" : 1,
  "field3" : 1,
  "field4" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you explain , using words, how this transformation should work ?

Comment: @Luuk : Edited my question , let me know if this is enough

Answer (score 1):

I was able to partially achieve it

1. Convert array of string to array of int
2. perform Addition of array
3. Convert above to string
4. Split above string

   ```
   [
      {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
          "binaryarray": ["=toInteger", 0]
        }
        },
      {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
          //
          // Sums
          "sumIntData": "=intSum(@(1,binaryarray))"
        }
      },
      {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
          "sumIntData": ["=toString", 0]
        }
        },
      {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
          "PID3": "=split('', @(1,sumIntData))"
        }
        }
    ]
   ```

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: still not able to edit my answer